# Flask-Admin Adding new Keyword in Proxy Association

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-admin

Would any know the best way to achieve the following with flask-admin

I have two models User and Keyword which have a relationship one to many.

What I want to do is in the create or edit form allows users to select the available keyword or add a new keyword in the Create User view.

At the moment I am able to achieve one or the other but not both together.

Using inline model, I am able to allow user to add new keyword in the Create View for User, but the keyword field will be overwritten. When not using inline model, flask-admin correctly display the Select2Field allow user to select multiple keyword from the Keyword model.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))

    # Association proxy of "user_keywords" collection to "keyword" attribute - a list of keywords objects.
    keywords = association_proxy('user_keywords', 'keyword')
    # Association proxy to association proxy - a list of keywords strings.
    keywords_values = association_proxy('user_keywords', 'keyword_value')

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self.name = name


class UserKeyword(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_keyword'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    keyword_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('keyword.id'), primary_key=True)
    special_key = db.Column(db.String(50))

    # bidirectional attribute/collection of "user"/"user_keywords"
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref("user_keywords", cascade="all, delete-orphan"))

    # reference to the "Keyword" object
    keyword = relationship("Keyword")
    # Reference to the "keyword" column inside the "Keyword" object.
    keyword_value = association_proxy('keyword', 'keyword')

    def __init__(self, keyword=None, user=None, special_key=None):
        self.user = user
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.special_key = special_key


class Keyword(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'keyword'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    keyword = db.Column('keyword', db.String(64))

    def __init__(self, keyword=None):
        self.keyword = keyword

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Keyword(%s)' % repr(self.keyword)




class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    """ Flask-admin can not automatically find a association_proxy yet. You will
        need to manually define the column in list_view/filters/sorting/etc.
        Moreover, support for association proxies to association proxies
        (e.g.: keywords_values) is currently limited to column_list only."""

    column_list = ('id', 'name', 'keywords', 'keywords_values')
    column_sortable_list = ('id', 'name')
    column_filters = ('id', 'name', 'keywords')
    form_columns = ('name', 'keywords')


class KeywordAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_list = ('id', 'keyword')
```

Comment: You'll have to put in a minimum of code to allow people to help you. Otherwise it is very complicated. How does your model look? How do you refer to Flask-admin?

Comment: Thank you , i have updated the question with a slim version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I've been looking into this and came up with an answer and thought I'll share it here incase someone is interested.

In my ModelView I wrote an ajax function.

```
  @expose('/ajax/add_keyword/', methods=('POST',))
    def ajax_add_category(self):


        if Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=request.form.get('keyword')).first():
            return 'Already exist', 500

        keyword = Keyword(keyword=request.form.get('category'))

     
    
        db.session.add(keyword)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'id': keyword.id, 'text': keyword.keyword})
```

in my edit_view and create_view, I added a simple JQuery and firing off the Select2 trigger.

```
 <label for="keyword">Keyword</label>
      <input type="text" name="keyword">
      <input class='add_keyword' type="submit" value="Add">
     


<script>

    $('.add_keyword').click( function() {

        category = $('[name="keyword"]');
        $.post("{{ get_url('.ajax_add_keyword') }}", 
              {
                keyword : keyword.val() ,
              } , function(data, status) {
                var newOption = new Option(data.text, data.id, false, true);
                $('#categories').append(newOption).trigger('change');
        });
    });
  </script>
```

this is a quick and dirty solution but it can be clean up to look more neatly.